# database hosting for desktop applications

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, hosting, desktop

I need a database hosting solution for my java desktop application.The java app must connect to the remote database via internet through jdbc.i,ve searched web but only web hosting with database comes up,remote database must be configured with username password..hostname ,portno,database name which later can be used to connect to that db through jdbc .Can SomeBody help finding Websites dedicated for that kind of purpose? Thanks

Comment: You can host your own mysql/postgres database for free...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try it yet but I had the same requirement and found [this from xeround](http://xeround.com/blog/2012/03/free-cloud-services-for-application-developers)